# Can not draw or change pixels' color on QImage

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to QT and now facing a problem with function `QImage::setPixel` and `QPainter::drawPoint`

I have mainwindow and a widget in it, called drawing area. The drawing area using layout with a label in it, which contains QImage converted to QPixmap. Unfortunately the functions I use to draw points give no result.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{ 
ui->setupUi(this);

area = new DrawingArea(this);
area->setGeometry(0,0,this->width(),this->height()/2);
area->show();

button = new QPushButton("Draw", this);
int bwidth = 100, bheight = 50;
button->setGeometry(200, 300, bwidth, bheight);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(getPoint()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
delete button;
delete area;
}

void MainWindow::getPoint(){
area->clearPoints();
area->makePoint(ui->textEdit->toPlainText().toInt(), ui->textEdit_2-
>toPlainText().toInt());
area->makePoint(ui->textEdit_3->toPlainText().toInt(), ui->textEdit_4-
>toPlainText().toInt());
area->makePoint(ui->textEdit_5->toPlainText().toInt(), ui->textEdit_6-
>toPlainText().toInt());
area->showPoints();
}
```

DrawinArea.cpp

```
#include "drawingarea.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPainter>

DrawingArea::DrawingArea(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
setAutoFillBackground(true);

canvas = new QImage(600, 500, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QRgb val = qRgb(189,149,39);
canvas->fill(Qt::gray);
canvas->setPixel(4,4,val);
canvas->setPixel(5,4,val);

imgDisplayer = new QLabel;
imgDisplayer->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*canvas));


displayer = new QLabel;

auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(imgDisplayer);
layout->addWidget(displayer);
}

void DrawingArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */){
//
}
void DrawingArea::clearPoints(){
points.clear();
}

void DrawingArea::makePoint(int x, int y){
Point *temp = new Point(x,y);
points.push_back(*temp);
free(temp);
}

void DrawingArea::showPoints(){

displayer->clear();
QPainter painter(canvas);
QPen pen;
pen.setWidth(1);
pen.setColor(Qt::red);
painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.end();
QString text;
for(size_t i = 0; i < points.size();i++){
    text+= ("P" + QString::number(i) + " (X: " + 
QString::number(points[i].x) +
            "; Y: " + QString::number(points[i].y) + ");\n");
    painter.drawPoint(points[i].x, points[i].y);
}
imgDisplayer->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*canvas));
displayer->setText(text);
displayer->setGeometry(300, 80, 100,100);




displayer->show();
imgDisplayer->show();

}

DrawingArea::~DrawingArea(){
delete canvas;
delete displayer;
delete imgDisplayer;
}
```

Comment: Why have you shown an empty `DrawingArea::paintEvent` implementation?

Comment: I just pasted the code I have and didn't notice it. Or Do you mean it's necessary to describe drawing logic in paintEvent? I actually do not use paintEvent to draw as I try to draw points with painter.

Comment: You're only setting two pixels.  Are you certain they're not set?  Try saving the image as a file and inspecting it with a viewer.  What happens if you change the background colour from `Qt::gray` to `Qt::red`?  Is the change visible?

Comment: I found out, that I can not even save the image. I call `canvas->save("save.jpg")` after `setPixel` method calling. It has no result.

Comment: Calling painter.end(); before drawing will tell QPainter to release all resources, hence no drawing. So you shouldn't call [QPainter::end()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#end) before starting to draw and typically you don't need to call it at all.

Comment: @Blechdose I removed 'painter.end();', but still haven't succeed with drawing and even saving the image. I'm new to Qt, so still can't figure out what the root of problem is

Comment: What happens when you try to save the image?  Any console messages?  Try saving as a png or ppm rather than jpg.

Comment: You're not adding your layout to the drawing area. Add setLayout(layout) in your DrawingArea constructor at the bottom. Is it working then? Otherwise I'll have a look later on.

Comment: Well, the problem is that your image is way bigger than your label. Make the image size smaller and pen width way bigger and you'll see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal example. Hope that helps :)

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->drawButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){ // Lambda to keep example small. You may also just have a own method
        auto x = ui->xLineEdit->text().toInt();
        auto y = ui->yLineEdit->text().toInt();

        const QPixmap *pixmap = ui->imageLabel->pixmap();
        QImage image(QSize(600, 400), QImage::Format_RGB32);
        if (pixmap) {
            image = pixmap->toImage();
        } else {
            image.fill(Qt::gray);
        }

        QPainter painter(&image);
        auto pen = painter.pen();
        pen.setColor(Qt::red);
        pen.setWidth(5);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawPoint(x, y);
        ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
        ui->textLabel->setText(ui->textLabel->text().append("\nP(%1,%2)").arg(QString::number(x), QString::number(y)));
    });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>521</width>
    <height>450</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="imageLabel">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string/>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="textLabel">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Points:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>y:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="yLineEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="xLineEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>x:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="drawButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Draw</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>521</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Best regards